# Get tkinter Entry content (same variable names)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a `tkinter` window that will generate an entry widget for every `int` of a previous input.

(`for i in range(x)`) this means that this window can have as many entry boxes as the user wants, this also means that each entry box has the same variable name.

to get some context the widgets generate like this.

```py
for cam in range(camera_number):
    cam_entrances_label = tk.Label(text="cam" + str(cam) + "entrances")
    cam_entrances_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(values=[1, 2, 3])
    cam_entrances_dropdown.place(x=10, y=240 + (cam * 120))
    cam_entrances_label.place(x=10, y=220 + (cam * 120))
    cam_exits_label = tk.Label(text="cam" + str(cam) + "exits")
    cam_exits_label.place(x=10, y=270 + (cam * 120))
    cam_exits_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(values=[1, 2, 3])
    cam_exits_dropdown.place(x=10, y=290 + (cam * 120))
```

I now need to `get` each value for each of those Entry widgets and *`append`* them all to two different lists, however there is no way of differentiating between each box due to them having the same variable name.

Is there some other solution that will accomplish the same goal as to generate however many widgets as reacquired while being able to differentiate between them so their content can be retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are creating these Entry widgets, append them in a list. Then when you want to get the values of all entry widget just loop over that list and append the values you get into new lists

```py
list_ = []

for cam in range(camera_number):
    cam_entrances_label = tk.Label(text="cam" + str(cam) + "entrances")
    cam_entrances_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(values=[1, 2, 3])
    cam_entrances_dropdown.place(x=10, y=240 + (cam * 120))
    cam_entrances_label.place(x=10, y=220 + (cam * 120))
    cam_exits_label = tk.Label(text="cam" + str(cam) + "exits")
    cam_exits_label.place(x=10, y=270 + (cam * 120))
    cam_exits_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(values=[1, 2, 3])
    cam_exits_dropdown.place(x=10, y=290 + (cam * 120))
    
    list_.append((cam_entrances_dropdown,cam_exits_dropdown)) #2 widgets stored as a tuple
    
cam_entrances_dropdown_values,cam_exits_dropdown_values = [],[]
    
for l in list_:
    e1,e2 = l # unpack the tuple
    cam_entrances_dropdown_values.append(e1.get())
    cam_exits_dropdown_values.append(e2.get())

print(cam_entrances_dropdown_values,cam_exits_dropdown_values)
```

Comment: That worked almost perfectly, the only issue is that it will return every item of the list as a string not an integer, but that should be relatively easy to fix. Thanks a lot!